# WSO2 Message Broker (2.1.1): WebService API

Tags: wsdl, wso2, messagebroker

Is there documentation on the WebServices API? I found the WSDL of the Message Broker, I miss the message description in the WSDL.

https:/localhost:9443/services/EventBrokerService?wsdl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, There is no document for the web-services API in WSO2 MB. You have to manually check the parameters and other soap action via WSDL. Please find the blog for ["DISCOVERING ADMIN SERVICES IN A WSO2 (CARBON) SERVER"](http://www.nuwanbando.com/2012/11/discovering-admin-services-in-a-wso2-carbon-server/)